# Android layout bypass image with text

Tags: android, layout

I want to achieve android layout for text and image to be as shown on the left pic, however with ImageSpan and in-lining image into text at start gives me only what's on the right pic.

Are there any solutions to beautifully bypass large image with text?

```
|-------------| texttexttexttexttext   |-------------| 
|             | texttexttexttexttext   |             | 
|   image     | texttexttexttexttext   |   image     | 
|             | texttexttexttexttext   |             |
|-------------| texttexttexttexttext   |-------------| texttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext    texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext    texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext    texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
|
```

Comment: I asked a similar question. The answer I got was 'not really possible, roll your own'

Answer (score 2):

Possible by using an WebView and writing HTML-code. Might also be doable by inserting the HTML into an TextView with [Html.fromHtml(String, Html.ImageGetter, Html.TagHandler)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html). See an example of using ImageGetter [here](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/06/textview-with-html-content.html).

Comment: Yeah with HTML it's supposed to be as easy as <img src=url align=left /> text, but in TextView it doesn't change situation from Right pic to Left pic. And having WebView in ListView item when there are many of them doesn't look like solution either :(